# WMICLASS.Create(), returning variables?

Tags: powershell, process

In Powershell, running a process remotely (software install):

```
$computers = Get-Content "C:\computer.txt"

foreach ($computer in $computers) {


#The location of the file  
    $Install = "\\$computer\C$\Software"

#The Install string can have commands aswell
  $InstallString = "$Install\IE11-Windows6.1-x64-en-us.exe $arguments"

    ([WMICLASS]"\\$computer\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process").Create($InstallString)
#Output the install result to your Local C Drive
    Out-File -FilePath c:\installed.txt -Append -InputObject "$computer"}
```

Is there a way to return variables or the status of this install? Or wait until the process is done?

Answer (score 0):

Locally, you can use [`Wait-Process`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849813(v=wps.620).aspx):

```
$InstallProcess = ([WMICLASS]"Win32_Process").Create($InstallString)
Wait-Process -Id $InstallProcess.ProcessId
```

Unfortunately, `Wait-Process` doesn't support remoting.

---

Here's a poor man's [remote equivalent using Get-Process](http://blag.koveras.org/2010/12/06/how-to-wait-for-a-remote-process-in-powershell/):

```
$InstallProcess = ([WMICLASS]"\\$computer\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process").Create($InstallString)
do { Get-Process -Id $InstallProcess.ProcessId -ComputerName $computer } while ($?)
```

Comment: I attempted this but got a no process found. Are you sure this will work on a remote PC, or is `Wait-Process` searching the local PC?

Comment: No luck there either, that is returning `Get-Process : Couldn't connect to remote machine.` even though the process did start